# Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected , Django 1.4

Tags: django, heroku

I am using Django 1.4 and trying to push it to Heroku. I get the following error. I have picked up settings and config from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django. just my django version is different.

> Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

I have tried every solution. I tried

> $ heroku create -stack cedar

Didn't work.
My requirements.txt file is correctly spelled and wsgi setting seems perfect. Django 1.6 works fine in heroku but django1.4 is troubling me.
Unluckily I cannot port my project to django 1.6 now.
Also foreman doesn't work for me.